# How to reduce reload time while deploying clojure web service?

Tags: clojure

I use Linux/upstart to start my jar.
I do it in such a way:

1. lein uberjar produces myapp.jar
2. copy myapp.jar via scp to a dedicated server
3. ssh to the dedicated server
4. stop myapp.jar
5. copy jar to the destination directory (hence upstart can find it)
6. start myapp.jar

There are several problems:

1. It's boring to make steps 1, 2, 3 and 6. I think it's possible to do it in a script, but I'm not sure it's a good idea to replace myapp.jar *before* stopping myapp. Is it safe to change jar file while it *runs*?
2. Delay between steps 5 and 7 are about 10 seconds. Is it possible to *update* myapp.jar *immediately*? And more interesting: is it possible to update on the spot: for example I have opened connections and I would like to save them.
3. Is it possible to do it like Erlang does? Deploy and if it fails it will load previous version.

Comment: wouldn't this question be better suited for e.g. serverfault?  it's basically about automating your deploy and beside the random fact, that you use lein to build your fat jar, next to nothing specific to clojure.

Comment: I agree that this question doesn't belong here. As far as I am aware neither Clojure nor the JVM provides a way for you to do this. But you could look at something like Ansible to script from step 2 onwards.

Comment: I agree this is better suited for serverfault. Here are some notes anyway. You can send a stop signal to jvm from within a script, it does not have to be manual. As far as smart updating goes, that would probably involve having a gateway program that decides who serves the requests. You would run your old and new jvm apps at the same time and the gateway would somehow choose among them. I bet serverfault people will have some good input on this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question consists of several parts, let me answer them each by each.

Your'are right, replacing a jar file is not a good idea. You'd better back up the file (copy it into a `backup` directory) rather than just overwrite it.

If you are really curious about the startup time and downtime gap, there are a couple of options for that. First, to maintain a layout with more than one working nodes and a proxy which distributes incoming requests between them. So you update the first node, and while it's offline, all the requests go to the second one. Then you update the second and you'are good. But it requires you to obtain some ops skills first.

The second option is, you perform hot code reloading. Briefly, expose an nREPL port on your production server. Then you connect to it from Emacs or any other editor, open an updated namespace and press `C-c C-k` which evaluates the whole namespace on remote machine. As the result, you update the code in runtime without restarting the machine. But remember, the changes won't be saved after reload.

A small note, you'd better automate the process with Ansible. It's a tool where you declare your actions in a YAML file. The result would be a set of instructions that look simple and easy to maintain. Ansible considers plenty of things under the hood. For example, it can create backups automatically when you try to overwrite a file.